# Port 457 on SMTP server?

Tags: smtp, email-server, vps, port

I hope this question is valid on here, if not I apologize.

I have a VPS server setup with PowerMTA and InterSpire, I just purchased the server and then I had an "expert" setup the rest. The VPS has all needs for a regular email server setup, like all ports open and rDNS.

Now my issue is the fact that whenever I try to create an email campaign and test it, by sending it to my own hotmail and gmail account. The email goes straight in the spam folder. 
I know my IPs are clean as I have tested them, I know the email content isn't spam as I have also tested that to be 100% clear. 
But then I read somewhere, that often times the issue is the SMTP settings. I am slightly familiar with the different SMTP ports and know the usual one is port 25. However the one setup on my server is port 457, which I have never heard of and can't find any information about when searching for it on Google.

The "expert" tells me that the setup is properly made, but I have doubt and want to make sure regarding this port number.

Underneath is the Hotmail email source code, which categorized as spam

```
Received: from CY1NAM02HT172.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10a6:3:1a::14) by HE1P190MB0348.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS via
 HE1PR0501CA0004.EURPRD05.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Wed, 11 Oct 2017 22:33:29 +0000
Received: from CY1NAM02FT036.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.74.52) by CY1NAM02HT172.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.74.224) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.20.77.10; Wed, 11
 Oct 2017 22:33:28 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is 000.00.000.00)
 smtp.mailfrom=domain.com; outlook.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;outlook.com; dmarc=none action=none header.from=domain.com;
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: weagill.com does not designate
 permitted sender hosts)
Received: from api7.mydomain.com (000.00.000.00) by
 CY1NAM02FT036.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.75.124) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id
 15.20.77.10 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 11 Oct 2017 22:33:28 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker: OriginalChecksum:BC992A824A633B40E95CDFBA9D9DCFAB98F7CF27563607D0409892D8DC8FEC87;UpperCasedChecksum:9494047B3F3928A0EF261AE4497490C3F0881861EC441F2C914B60D389C185CD;SizeAsReceived:366;Count:10
To: <testreceiveemail@outlook.com>
Subject: Test Email System
Message-ID: <82cd27fb25d6274f943387cf1dfee31a@mydomain.com>
Return-Path: contact@domain.com
Date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 22:33:27 +0000
From: <contact@domain.com>
Reply-To: <contact@domain.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 10
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: e3f87ba3-ae12-4d3f-ddd9-08d510f81826
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;CY1NAM02FT036;1:LKGiTZfrkJDht58eRPjjnwaf5dHCJUEyrSMNqR69Vdauemu+dWL+vPgeAjORxFa2qa/1TGfnnNtdxWWA5ONrGV/K7NRecNe8b+Dh7UaKid8+dXQB7QNBVSd6VTFB7NDr
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(98901004);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:CY1NAM02HT172;H:api7.mydomain.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: CY1NAM02FT036.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: e3f87ba3-ae12-4d3f-ddd9-08d510f81826
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(23075)(22001)(5000083)(610149)(8291501071);SRVR:CY1NAM02HT172;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;CY1NAM02HT172;3:CLZG/fxS7bDVhbUHKwp3kHn1e2ixx0PWUFs3DTJW1zj2kr64yV0RqWjhZYbPBdS6bXiXViX/FsPWFo9GAATcuJTYNIj/XoEfdcXb+BDq3/1lF2QG/TjCYhmHGLx4UAEsSAiHLpdK8V5sYyqOysKnvozlucw+Tsi8CuUor83WagGFNIGFSGtMGDGTGAn1DvO+IprUDfxXRIdUNGRsqKsRPBUd6zxFrYekFPSYhzA8UtdXYnEcW2BdBozPTA0zHedLK01SgYUWyd4Xp25M9Gnxh2J8hxNkyxEKlSozNfCmod+fG0kEy8PUGfah1HExOkbi;25:rF/1wkl5whjmn8xlNQF9w76N/NMcqrUkZLDWc3TdA4+5+Hxpy1VLsqKwy5VwNMGd3LIALPsa8k7iX3UT86r+E+M8Q86j/+0RObaWVCW3BuTHIi6sULxsaAd+War+kqYRdlIEwS+pUW0TToRtWokhQaEPpcSiSOJEkI13T7nTS6YIJy0iY+wC5dfpAxItEmbLqydOuZDgayuSKnYhN9WnzOR2fsm/UCrXSdtutaFKVkJm/Ya8ZkSZ+AHs/A/i97YzuVxFLkpbZiuPAd6dKX6WDVmx7o9xuLRyi6LZfFBw70kzDW629mFWhL+qIsx2dJwPshjC8Idr5qS1IdtVelo2Yfa+cyfksnjHgxvIW+4IJMs=;31:5O3/23y09YSW6QpBXl5Kvx84qfPoiPNm26h5CYRlBNPz50FMJuEHv8j6/4RDNstNlrqGoAGuPFYYpeHR2O9m3vKyVhSkc/nRThg7e/aWXDh5G5D0HT2+Vn0sp1zmcuuhh+u/3SUdOHtIv5lBciVaTi2mSQw7E6eJGLYvH0JCFetvYcRWPfz8NuuBTj0+MflUn74qUCYhbnnHwycmb4C36n0OzqzsP2kN8aoDU4e9DEg=
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: CY1NAM02HT172:
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: 142.44.227.57
X-SID-PRA: CONTACT@DOMAIN.COM
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000700101)(100105000095)(100000701101)(100105300095)(100000702101)(100105100095)(444111536)(595095)(82015058);SRVR:CY1NAM02HT172;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000800101)(100110000095)(100000801101)(100110300095)(100000802101)(100110100095)(100000803101)(100110400095)(100000804101)(100110200095)(100000805101)(100110500095);SRVR:CY1NAM02HT172;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;CY1NAM02HT172;4:dfvZIOwvMFJh2qWv+VQZVz4U98IbpGr39NCQYp4ubHlY9nflcTZarNZ93htqo2bVIyl1KbeDHp+rlmnY/EqTrkdWbvPdRDTefRaA+u13aMPZO8R2sMbHurMvnZ+01or2fEwT6zYOCN6FjZTsG8O/fKvKq4gCjLUnf9SsTnPABgyX7GmfM65zsjuUWfC8HipXHZocWeONenWsK0ORZDADwt/3ddEfHocboohwTY6fZDAd24cIJZovUcc7WJjy2cF6;23:xv/SQRnXXehl3hk0Q5HOaNrxMuAlOirTiRDymf9yv49FKzIkvtWFXnQaOFWYBcXQagB9XFWJOFGJpHDSIx2uWpkSw74HZ/SWWkMHInw9nG1gf83YCsL5P+8cH0iVXNVXixquvwnGhDsozkBATUOLiHz5hWTMvtmFUdQeulN0vss=;6:Z+iDYmnQPjLRiCUAHIjjC6MuvRC/gyVcwImiwajSOxJoeao+lm7KNGWOu/VeMUFlpH0OUbNEhSKOVaMZ3G4DH9FhmKzjZQuSSpUjp6RuYVH9z3PoyYk4t3zUYlARr+VlWnMRqlW//moDSGN6HBHxYVP2kNVonq44jDNXDQE6yaHsd//J7G9bI0WcSgAK+EnkFQE1Kpd6bHE5n+g0g/k6pjs/MiyhqNGLAJveOFyP+CzTckCK+BxjwhK0GFBy084j8LK+zwzavE7L9YAE5DxbaSqfaxIOxASVtF9shIw9QGzyLYNCxUnkGmHAi5P6C9mEP6yHp/dK0YZ8gP2bvL+NDw==;5:ldY4Mpl6iB13bcjtmHK6U5MyicDA947IucWGTlWh9h2icw0lK8g4cp8jWApmRT0FbtjbpjZZZv8vqKsIMnmygxitmgfDI/GjJg8dMzvbMn3vpfYA9C+3KFZHAPhV8YenHEAbzNBX2Z/Lc0nY3J2Bvg==
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;CY1NAM02HT172;24:HmU8+tpGohU4IXfGqVSE9ohPlVij6e/FN5GwE39Vx2FQTPdU1WMQZzt/O+3ZjK4wbkUvwDX4Xio/OdsZKQgpg+wAxHMaixRyTb70Ge9Q30E=;7:P/N5sQLKjePfuJR4psoOu4BUpG5q8XbKOZafgLG97sQIAyd3iIpL/ceiMZOwxa6rxdLyPK/w/x6h2vbLeEMl5eMdG9Uq1nskndfYX+VeRuzCrjhT4vYbIpuz741YkIE41AWmjS9t7YSJo4EidC/VHmc2yRE7mdCp9hrjLwPfUFB8MQqqKca8z/ws874D+3ASMjEos4gJS/4n3o52Y+FnYe2czkxQiVQAjI+c+OXDC1c=
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Oct 2017 22:33:28.3896
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: CY1NAM02HT172
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.4980204
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.0077.017
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;HE1P190MB0348;27:yI4sJS7YKaRmYZEwNVojBegJ+0k5rg7mWDgSw23nUMORqoPtsAansNp+QbXSYRxXxUBRECmNukHRNQiILCkLIYGdn7GVNOBiGSvGEBRTsy0fO8Vs2pVWAFhGS0/c69pE
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;psp:0;auth:0;dest:J;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6375004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
X-Message-Info:
    qoGN4b5S4yqj4IaGpKlnGKT9fTpXsFuFEQAireWYeme97to4gxKZuA76zNUifWNm6Bdc1VV9v3+tfOHk29cexC4J7sXJ1NuPgP99kz0pZ+dtMR4K8HYzxwToR5Ucmee7alXHAvLCFaEOwani3e4v7FdA3atoe4KNwokGKgXOY6OhYurNCdeiQHH4D6H9zobl5RlL5eag9Dqd0w0Wzu5k+g==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    9bclqmd+TvztyTVRVuN1NGk6La0+XHh1I3WrbB7AGFwnxn7IqnPn4OSK7G8t53koBiFnhzGJefKc2fEFC+mlclqU0EnQ7Wcv3+BiIEz1x9ayem0LWrCwS3HJlM1aFOBP1zU4gfL6y8a8/glMc+1X3JQTQkGVdozwjukB4sCijF5J5eYyuvZq4eT5F7O4sH7UuCIBHvxmBjXvnp/jq8bt6zpjDt28WYWtLgmcFLxK7WbGejZiwik14qkS39tx4ulGhZfkZJ4i2JGYk7m5WAlH6A==
MIME-Version: 1.0

Hi,
This is a test of the emailing system. If you received this ok, then
everything is working as it should.
```

Comment: If you use the term `email campaign`, then most likely it **is** spam.

Comment: @anx the terms "email campaign" is simply what InterSpire calls it when creating an email to send out.

Comment: @anx I really appreciate the feedback and will look into the points you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: For a mail campaign you should use product like mailchimp, that got burst control to not flood a host and getting tagged as spam imediatly.

Answer (score 1):

To receive internet e-mail a SMTP server needs to listen to port 25, but the port number that your server accepts and which you need configure in your mail client to send outgoing e-mail is not very relevant, TCP [port 587](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent) (or the albeit [deprecated 465](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS)) would be more conventional but is not better or worse than 457.

The header you posted:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is 000.00.000.00)
 smtp.mailfrom=domain.com; outlook.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;outlook.com; dmarc=none action=none header.from=domain.com;
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: weagill.com does not designate
 permitted sender hosts)
```

Would  indicate that neither your outgoing mailserver nor your domain is completely configured yet.

You still need to set up [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC).

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I have changed the domain and mailserver situation. As I had made the mistake of changing the domain in one of the settings, which didn't show properly. I will look into the rest, thank you.